# Excluding a value from the return result of MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a problem and I'm not finding the answer. I'm querying a MySql table during my java process and I would like to exclude some rows from the return of my query.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    o.offer_id,
    o.external_cat,
    o.cat,
    o.shop,
    o.item_id,
    oa.value
FROM
    offer AS o,
    offerattributes AS oa
WHERE
    o.offer_id = oa.offer_id
        AND (cat = 1200000 OR cat = 12050200
            OR cat = 13020304
            OR cat = 3041400
            OR cat = 3041402)
        AND (oa.attribute_id = 'status_live_unattached_pregen'
            OR oa.attribute_id = 'status_live_attached_pregen'
            OR oa.attribute_id = 'status_dead_offer_getter'
            OR oa.attribute_id = 'most_recent_status')
        AND (oa.value = 'OK'
            OR oa.value='status_live_unattached_pregen'
            OR oa.value='status_live_attached_pregen'
            OR oa.value='status_dead_offer_getter')
```

The trick here is that I need the value to be 'OK' in order to continue my process but I don't need mysql to return it in its response, I only need the other values to be returned, for the moment its returning two rows by query, one with the 'OK' value and another with one of the other values.

I would like the return value to be like this:

```
'000005261383370', '10020578', '1200000', '562', '1000000_157795705', 'status_live_attached_pregen'
```

for my query, but it returns:

```
'000005261383370', '10020578', '1200000', '562', '1000000_157795705', 'OK'
'000005261383370', '10020578', '1200000', '562', '1000000_157795705', 'status_live_attached_pregen'
```

Some help would really be appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: You want to return rows who's `oa.value` is 'OK', no rows who's `oa.value` is 'OK'?

Comment: I need MySql to just check if value is 'OK' when `oa.attribute_id` is equal to 'status_live_unattached_pregen', 'status_live_attached_pregen', 'status_dead_offer_getter' and I need it to return the values when `oa.attribute_id` is equal to 'most_recent_status'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with an `INNER JOIN` on the self I think:

```
SELECT o.offer_id
    ,o.external_cat
    ,o.cat
    ,o.shop
    ,o.item_id
    ,oa.value
FROM offer AS o
INNER JOIN offerattributes AS oa
    ON o.offer_id = oa.offer_id
INNER JOIN offerattributes AS oaOK
    ON oaOK.offer_id = oa.offer_id
        AND oaOK.value = 'OK'
WHERE o.cat IN (1200000,12050200,13020304,3041400,3041402)
    AND oa.attribute_id IN ('status_live_unattached_pregen','status_live_attached_pregen','status_dead_offer_getter','most_recent_status')
    AND oa.value IN ('status_live_unattached_pregen','status_live_attached_pregen','status_dead_offer_getter');
```

By doing a self-`JOIN` with the restriction of value `OK`, it will limit the result set to `offer_id`s that have an `OK` response, but the `WHERE` clause will still retrieve the values you need. Based on your description, I think this is what you were looking for.

I also converted your implicit cross `JOIN` to an explicit `INNER JOIN`, as well as changed your `OR`s to `IN`, should be more performant this way.